# Continuous scroll on Wacom

Tags: xorg, wacom, scrolling, mouse-scroll

After going through several posts, I am able to configure my Wacom bamboo pen to scroll up/down by assigning pen keys 2/3 the actions from buttons 4/5 from X11.

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pen stylus" Button 2 button 5
```

However, this requires me to click multiple times to scroll just a bit. Is it possible to configure something like `while(pressed) scroll up`?